# IDE says there are nullability issues with custom CallResult method, which is wrong

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the custom `DeserializeInternal` method to indicate whether the deserialization was successful or not. It results into a `CallResult<T>`.

The issue is that Visual Studio highlights the line `return dataHandler(desResult.Data)` as possible null reference. `if (!desResult)` literally performs the check whether it was successful or not. It is not null for sure.

What should I change in the `CallResult<T>` class in order to disable that nullability issue, because it's wrong? If `desResult.Success == true`, then `Data` is available for sure. If it's `false`, then the `Error` object is available for sure.

```cs
public async ValueTask<Guid> SubscribeAsync<T>(KrakenSubscribeRequest request, Func<T, ValueTask> dataHandler) where T : class
{
    // TODO: Log all responses
    await SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    _subscriptionManager.Subscribe("match-pattern", request, InternalHandler);

    return Guid.Empty;

    ValueTask InternalHandler(Notification notification)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            var stringData = (T)Convert.ChangeType(notification.ToString(), typeof(T));
            return dataHandler(stringData);
        }

        var desResult = notification.Data.DeserializeInternal<T>();
        if (!desResult)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Failed to deserialize data into type {Type}: {Error}", typeof(T), desResult.Error);
            return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
        }

        return dataHandler(desResult.Data); // TODO: warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 'arg' in 'ValueTask Func<T, ValueTask>.Invoke(T arg)'.
    }
}
```

### Wrapper

```cs
public abstract record Error(int? Code, string Message, object? Data);

public record DeserializeError(string Message, object? Data) : Error(null, Message, Data);

public record CallResult<T>(bool Success, T? Data, Error? Error) where T : class
{
    public CallResult(T data) : this(true, data, null)
    {
    }

    public CallResult(Error error) : this(false, null, error)
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(CallResult<T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Success;
    }
}

public static class SerializationManager
{
    public static CallResult<T> DeserializeInternal<T>(this JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions? options = default)
        where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            return new CallResult<T>(element.Deserialize<T>(options)!);
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            return new CallResult<T>(new DeserializeError($"Deserialize JsonException: {ex.Message}", null));
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException ex)
        {
            return new CallResult<T>(new DeserializeError($"Deserialize NotSupportedException: {ex.Message}", null));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new CallResult<T>(new DeserializeError($"Deserialize Unknown Exception: {ex.Message}", null));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` condition tests `desResult` (using the implicit operator), but it doesn't test the value of the `Data` Property. If you add, for example, `if (!desResult || desResult.Data is null) { }` it should not complain. Maybe it's not the test you want here, but you could check that after. -- Not sure what it says about this: `var stringData = (T)Convert.ChangeType(notification.ToString(), typeof(T));`

Comment: @Jimi, `(T)Convert.ChangeType(notification.ToString(), typeof(T));` is fine. I ended up doing `#pragma warning disable CS8604 // Possible null reference argument.
            return dataHandler(desResult.Data);
#pragma warning restore CS8604 // Possible null reference argument.` which is not so great.

Comment: @Jimi, I'm trying to find a way to get the result without it complaining about the nullability.

Comment: Then test `desResult.Data` for null as you did for `desResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of Net6.0) there is no way to do what you want with implicit `bool` operator. However it is possible by using the `bool Success` property at the caller side, and describing which other property is not null when the property value is `true` or `false` using the [MemberNotNullWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullwhenattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute at the definition side, e.g.

```cs
public record CallResult<T>(
    [property:MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(CallResult<T>.Data))] // <--
    [property:MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(CallResult<T>.Error))] // <--
    bool Success, T? Data, Exception? Error) where T : class
{
    // ... (same as the original)
}
```

and now

```cs
if (!desResult.Success) // <--
{
    // do something with desResult.Error
    Error error = desResult.Error; // <-- No warning
    // ...
    return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}

// else do something with desResult.Data
return dataHandler(desResult.Data); // <-- No warning
```